# Flex: cannot control size of scroll bar thumb when skinned

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, scrollbar, skinning

I have this problem where the scroll bar's thumb is too small when I apply a skin programmatically. There's no problem when I apply it in the CSS.

main.css:

```
.myscrolls {
    thumbUpSkin: Embed(source="thumb-default.png",
        scaleGridLeft="7", scaleGridTop="5", scaleGridRight="8", scaleGridBottom="7");
```

The above looks fine, but if I try to change the thumb programmatically in the ActionScript later, the thumb is too small, which causes enormous margins between the thumb and the ends of the scroll bar.

ScrollbarColour.as:

```
[Embed(source="thumb-non-default.png",
   scaleGridLeft="7", scaleGridTop="5", scaleGridRight="8", scaleGridBottom="7")]const cThumbNonDefault:Class;
```

The problem is most likely related to this warning that I get about the above line:

> ScrollbarColour_cThumbNonDefault does not extend the 'DefineSprite' asset base class 'flash.display.Sprite'

But if I take away those `scaleGrid*` members from the ActionScript, the warning goes away.

I used the Flex 3.5 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

However, I made all those `Embed`s on the stack. If I made them (`static`) members of `ScrollbarColour`, I was able to get those attributes to work. I really don't get this language.